# SQS messages monitored through CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am receiving SNS notifications and I have subscribed an SQS to it. I am able to poll my messages and also view their content. The contents of the messages include pass/fail status of automation. Is it possible to create cloudwatch metrics based on the contents of the metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo code in pyhton to give you an idea:

```
import json
import boto3

# Initialize CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Your code to parse the incoming SQS message
    # Assume that the status is stored in a variable called 'status'
    # ...

    # Put custom metric data into CloudWatch
    cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
        Namespace='MyCustomNamespace',
        MetricName='MyCustomMetricName',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'STATUS',
                'Value': status  # Use the parsed status here
            },
        ],
        Value=1  # Increment the metric by 1
    )
```

1. Subscribe AWS Lambda to SQS Queue
2. Parse the Message in Lambda
3. Send Metrics to CloudWatch
4. Create CloudWatch Alarms and Dashboards